# Trying to get the time difference between two time points in R. I have NAs in the data set and i cant find a way to do it correctly

Tags: r, time, difftime

My data is currently in two separate columns

T1 example looks like 2020-05-01 09:00:00 PM

T2 example took like 2020-05-02 04:00:00 AM

This data also contains NAs

Data mode and class is characters

I would like to know the difference between these in hours.

I tried a function like so

```
df$TimeElapsedhours <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (!is.na(df$T1[i])) {
    df$TimeElapsedDays[i] <- difftime(df$T2[i], df$T1[i], units = c("hours"))
  }
}
```

but the values dont seem right it is giving me absurd answers higher than what is right something is going on.

I tried something like this

```
df$DIF <- as.numeric(difftime(strptime(df$T1 , "%I:%M %p" ),strptime(df$T2 , "%I:%M %p" ),units='hours'))
```

and it returns all NAs

So... how can i find the time difference between two time points with data that includes NAs

Comment: Please provide reproducible input data using `dput` as requested at the top of the [tag:r] tag home page.

Comment: We cant help you without a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

We don't need a `for` loop here, we can use `lubricate` to parse the date time, and `mutate` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(T1 = parse_date_time(c("2020-05-01 09:00:00 PM",
                                        "2020-05-01 10:48:00 PM"), 
                                      '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'),
                 T2 = parse_date_time(c("2020-05-02 04:00:00 AM",
                                        "2020-05-02 05:45:00 AM"), 
                                      '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'))

df <- df %>% mutate(TimeElapsedDays = difftime(df$T2, df$T1, units = c("hours")))
```

This gives us

```
> df
                   T1                  T2 TimeElapsedDays
1 2020-05-01 21:00:00 2020-05-02 04:00:00      7.00 hours
2 2020-05-01 22:48:00 2020-05-02 05:45:00      6.95 hours
```

With NAs this will give an NA in the TimeElapsedDays col as below

```
df1 <- data.frame(T1 = parse_date_time(c("2020-05-01 09:00:00 PM",NA), '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'),
                 T2 = parse_date_time(c("2020-05-02 04:00:00 AM","2020-05-02 04:00:00 AM"), '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'))

df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(TimeElapsedDays = difftime(df1$T2, df1$T1, units = c("hours")))

> df2
                   T1                  T2 TimeElapsedDays
1 2020-05-01 21:00:00 2020-05-02 04:00:00         7 hours
2                <NA> 2020-05-02 04:00:00        NA hours
```

But we can remove that

```
df2 <- na.omit(df2)
df2
> df2
                   T1                  T2 TimeElapsedDays
1 2020-05-01 21:00:00 2020-05-02 04:00:00         7 hours
```

Comment: I am still getting the same issue. For example this code is telling me that the difference between


"2020-05-01 10:48:00 PM" and "2020-05-02 05:45:00 AM"
is 18.95 hours.  it should be : 6.95



I also need it to keep the time part for hours and minutes. So I simply kept the format I had and entered it into the formula like so


df <- data.frame(T1 = olddf$T1,
                 T2 = olddf $T2)
df <- df %>% mutate(TimeElapsedDays = difftime(df$T2, df$T1, units = c("hours")))

Comment: I've edited my answer with one that works as wanted. Sorry I didn't see the first version gave an incorrect answer!